# How to send Available Stanza in XMPP IOS using XMPPFramework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I am sending  `<presence/>` stanza to make user online in XMPP, but i am receiving something like below :

```
<presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="user8@192.168.0.167/Object" to="user7@192.168.0.167"><x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update"><photo></photo></x><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework" ver="k6gP4Ua5m4uu9YorAG0LRXM+kZY="></c></presence>
```

in it there is no type available, can any one please help me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

when there is no type in xmpp `<presence>` it's always showing availability.for another types like `away` or `unavailable` there is a type.for more information please see [https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#presence]